# Does layout-sw320dp-h320dp make sense?

Tags: android, screen-resolution

Should I use `sw320dp-h320dp` qualifier for devices with 320 dp height or `sw320dp` includes `h320dp`?

Comment: i doubt if `h` qualifier is even supported.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar according to this documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html yes

Comment: Okay thanks. So `sw` (smallest width) is regardless of screen orientation. It will make sure that at least one dimension of screen(width or height) must be at least equal (or greater) to the `sw` qualifier value. `h` (Available screen height) means minimum height of the device must be equal (or greater) than the `h` qualifier value and the height is relative to the device orientation.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar `sw` means "at least one" or "both"?

Comment: at least one..!